# java spring repository filter by derived class

Tags: java, spring, repository, criteria-api

Is there a way to filter by class derived from base class?

for example I have Animal.class, and I have AnimalRepository.
I want to find animal by type of derived class, so something like:

```
Animal animalRepository.findByDerivedClass(Class clazz);
```

At the same time I don't in advance which derived class it is. It can be Cat, Dog, or new I don't know about yet. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for example you can create a select with hibernate by type of class:

```
List<Animal> animal = (List<Animal>) getSession().createCriteria(Class clazz).list();
```

Comment: I was hoping for solution with repositories, but this also looks promising, will try it out.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer leaded me to criteria use (repositories can't do, so had to write custom method for repository, which means use of criteria)

Also note that this method, if used in repository, has to be declared according to jpa convention.

```
public <T extends Animal> List<T> findByDerivedClass(Class<T> clazz) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(clazz);
    Root<T> root = cq.from(clazz); // we pass clazz here again, because magic...
    cq.select(root);
    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```